# Contractive Sequences and Fixed Points

Tags: real-analysis

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnucS.jpg

So this is a review question for my intro to analysis class (final is tomorrow). I have been able to prove that the sequence is Cauchy but I don't see or know how to find the required fixed help. All help will be very much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to Math SE!  Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about how to typeset your question.  Generally image-based questions should be avoided.

Comment: Hint: Take any point and apply $f$ to it repeatedly. That is, consider the sequence $x_0,f(x_0),f(f(x_0)), f(f(f(x_0))),\dots$. What kind of sequence is this?